# is data- attributes posing any security issues?

Tags: html, security, custom-data-attribute

In html code, my project using data- attribute in several places like carousal, accordions, etc.

Is html data- attribute posing any security issue? Is there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a security issue, but a robust feature of modern HTML for storing and manipulating app specific data and making elements easily accessible to site scripts. Data attributes do not access or interact with databases, but serve to fill gaps where existing attributes are insufficient for the needs of your individual project, and their contents are [made readily available to your site scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) via the `.dataset` property in the web API. They also help us to avoid storing certain kinds of information in class names, which would be inappropriate, and can be changed dynamically in the DOM.

There is [language in the specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) noting that the data contained in these attributes is "private" and that accessing it externally is "inappropriate" but this is not a matter of security but rather standards. They're not private in the sense that they shouldn't be accessible or that they contain sensitive information, but rather that they are specific to this application and its needed functionality, that they are subject to change by the site's scripts for it's own purposes, and they can't and shouldn't be relied upon outside of their own context.

[Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) are primarily used to facilitate the scripts on the site by providing data for which other attributes are unsuitable. This is common in front end frameworks, where you want to be able to quickly apply complex UI interactions or layout changes by attaching options to a given element.

For example, Foundation has an option called Equalizer, which uses JavaScript to balance (or equalize) the height of parallel items within a common parent. One data attribute marks the container, another marks each item to be watched for height changes, and another optional attribute may contain options like whether the behavior changes when items are stacked.